# Are there any codes that work more effectively instead of loop in R?

Tags: r

Hi I'm new to R programming,
We know that **apply** family returns faster results than loops. I tried to explain what I want to do with a simple and small example below. When there is a large data, the run time also increases. For this reason, is there a more effective method instead of loop?

```
a <- 1; b <- 2; c <- 3; d <- 4; e <- 5

func1 <- function(x) x * x

x <- list('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

for (i in x) {
  if (exists("appnd1") == F) {
      appnd1<-func1(get(i))
  } else { 
      appnd1 <- rbind(appnd1, func1(get(i)))
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add it to the beginning of the script.    a<-1;b<-2;c<-3;d<-4;e<-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this quickly is with `sapply` and an anonymous function:

```
a <- 1; b <- 2; c <- 3;d <- 4; e <- 5
func1 <- function(x) x * x
x <- list('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
sapply(x, function(y) func1(get(y)))
## [1]  1  4  9 16 25
```

Comment: Let's make it a little more complex. Let's replace the first sample I gave with `a <- 1; b <- 2; c <- 3;` and then let's define two separate character object series `z1 <-"merge1"; z2 <-"merge2";z3 <-"merge3"; `  and `k1<-"data1"; k2 <-"data2"; k3 <-"data3";`  . These character values are merged into a function  `func2<- function(x,y)  paste(x,y)`
Finally. Can I generate dataframe result with using apply or lapply. Because I want the final set to be a dataframe, neither a matrix nor a list. thanks for your answers. @utubun @Miff

Comment: yes, you could use `sapply` for this more complex case, but I'd highly recommend rethinking how you're storing the data, using either vectors or lists for your z and k variables will make your code simpler and easier to debug (in my opinion). I don't think any of the `*apply` functions return a data.frame, you'd need to convert explicitly using `data.frame()` or `as.data.frame()`

Comment: Your question diverges too much from your original question. SO is about to get focused answers to focused questions. Please ask a new question having in mind that it's better if the answer will help other people.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `sapply` / `for` loops if you use `c()` instead of `list()` in your `x` definition:

```
x <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

func1(unlist(mget(x)))

# a  b  c  d  e 
# 1  4  9 16 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize `func1`, then check if `appnd1` exists and then check what to do:

```
tmp <- lapply(x, func1)
tmp <- do.call(rbind, tmp)

if(!exists("append1")){
  appnd1 <- tmp
} else{
  appnd1 <- rbind(appnd1, tmp)
}
```

Comment: tmp <- lapply(x, func1)  give  error message  Error in x * x : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: First convert the values in your list to numeric, or include it in your function as ```as.numeric(x) * as.numeric(x)```

Answer (score 0):

A bit convoluted way to sum variables :-) but here is my try

By the way what's inefficient in you loop is the successive rbinding of intermediate results.

```
# vertically bind computed values
appnd1 <- do.call(rbind,
  # apply func1 on values of listed variables
  lapply(
    # get values of listed variables
    lapply(
      x, 
      get,
      mode="numeric" # otherwise 'c' will return the function 'c()'
    ), 
  func1
  )
)
```

Got as result

```
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    4
[3,]    9
[4,]   16
[5,]   25
```